# Remove Editor margin in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code I've accidentally clicked something and the code editor got
some strange margins left and right. How can I get rid of it?

[image]

It moves only right but not left.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found just after creation of the question. Maybe it will be useful for somebody.

To get rid of if uncheck `View` -> `Appearance` -> `Centered Layout`